# Remove trailing commas generated when creating a CSV file

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove extra trailing commas which are generated when I create a CSV file using a macro.

[image]

Below is what I am using to create the CSV file.

```vb
Sub NEWMACRO ()

Dim complete_rec As String

mylogfile = FreeFile()

Dim rng As Range
Dim lLastRow As Integer
Dim lLastCol As Integer
    
Open "C:\File\ Range("A2").Value & ".csv" For Output Access Write As mylogfile

Set rng = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
lLastRow = rng.Row
lLastCol = rng.Column

For irow = 1 To lLastRow
    For icol = 1 To lLastCol
        If icol = 1 Then
            complete_rec = Application.Cells(irow, icol).Value
        Else
            complete_rec = complete_rec & "," & Application.Cells(irow, icol).Value
        End If
    Next icol
    
    complete_rec = complete_rec + " "
    Print #mylogfile, complete_rec
Next irow
Close mylogfile

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just highlight and delete these empty rows from your spreadsheet and try this code again? Perhaps I'm not understanding.

Comment: If you don't want those trailing commas then you need to read each row only up to the last value in that row, instead of assuming all rows have the same end point.

Comment: Amazing Tim, you are wonderful. It worked as required. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want those trailing commas then you need to read each row only up to the last value in that row, instead of assuming all rows have the same end point.

Here's one approach you could use:

```vb
Sub NEWMACRO()

    Dim sLine As String, sep As String
    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long, arr, mylogfile, rw As Long, col As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example
    'last occupied row on the sheet
    lLastRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        
    mylogfile = FreeFile()
    Open "C:\Temp\Test2.csv" For Output Access Write As mylogfile
    
    'loop over all rows
    For rw = 1 To lLastRow
        sLine = "": sep = ""
        'read only the occupied part of the row
        arr = asArray(ws.Range(ws.Cells(rw, 1), _
                       ws.Cells(rw, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)))
        For col = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            sLine = sLine & sep & arr(1, col)
            sep = ","
        Next col
        Print #mylogfile, sLine
    Next rw
    
    Close mylogfile
End Sub

'read a range into a 2D array, allowing for the single-cell case
Function asArray(rng As Range)
    Dim arr()
    If rng.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then
        ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        arr(1, 1) = rng.Value
        asArray = arr
    Else
        asArray = rng.Value
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Amazing Tim, you are wonderful. It worked as required. Thanks a lot